# Intermittent 404 error Eclipse + jsf + apache

Tags: java, apache, jsf

I'm working on a JSF project using Eclipse, JSF 2.1 and Apache 7.0. Every now and then, when i do some changes in my code (a managed bean for example) and try to run the project, the 404 error shows up. But it's a intermittent error. Yesterday i was coding normally and everything was working fine. When i tried to run the project, the apache gives me the 404 error. I've tried to close and open the eclipse, tried to clean the tomcat work directory, restart my pc (it worked once) but nothing works.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: it seems like eclipse is not deployong/redeploying your project files. Try to change deployment folder to tomcat directory on your server in eclipse and monitor the server logs as you do the changes

Answer (score 0):

If you do some changes in your code (a **managed bean** for example)
You *must* do the next

1. Build your project
2. Make sure that your project is loaded in your local server "tomcat"
3. Clean your local server "tomcat server"
4. Restart Your local server "tomcat server"
5. Run your project

Note
If you do some changes in your pages (a **XHTML** for example)
You *can run your pages directly* without need to restart your local server
And you will see the effects of your changes